# ruby net/ldap not able to handle errors

Tags: ruby, ldap

Recently I started coding in ruby. Although I am able to successfully bind, I have issues with the add operation. That is fine, I wanted to print the error message so that I could rectify the error. But unfortunately I'm not able to handle the LDAPError. Below is my code listed.

---

```
def add_user(user)
    dn = "cn=" + user.email_id + ", " + ConfigReader.instance.ldapBaseDn
    attr = {
      :cn              => user.email_id,
      :sn              => user.short_name,
      :email           => user.email_id,
      :mail            => user.email_id,
      :employeeNumber  => user.jabber_passwd,
      :buildingname    => user.image_url,
      :gidNumber       => user.age,
      :title           => user.title,
      :l               => user.location,
      :telephonenumber => user.phone_no,
      :info            => user.facebook_id,
      :dmdName         => user.twitter_id,
      :initials        => user.linkedin_id,
      :memberuid       => user.jabber_id,
      :userpassword    => ConfigReader.instance.userPassword,
      :co              => user.organization,
      :description     => user.biography,
      :objectclass     => ["top", "person","organizationalPerson","inetOrgPerson","extensibleObject"]
    }
      puts dn
      begin
        @ldap_connection.add(:dn => dn, :attributes => attr)
      rescue Net::LDAP::LdapError => error  
        puts "Failed"
      ensure
        puts error.backtrace
      end
    # unless @ldap_connection.add(:dn => dn, :attributes => attr)
    #   puts "Unable to create user" + user.email_id + " in ldap"
    # end
  end
```

---

Ensure block is reporting the below error :

`add_user': undefined method`backtrace' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from test.rb:7:in `block in <main>'
        from test.rb:5:in`each'
        from test.rb:5:in `'

I am using 
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'net/ldap'
    require 'singleton'

by the way. Can you please help me in this regard.

Comment: My problem here is that I am not able to get into the rescue block. I tried handling StandardError, Exception but of no avail. Is there a way I can get into rescue block print the cause of the exception so that I could continue further?

Answer (score 1):

Well! Once the operation fails, the cause is displayed using the code below :

ldap_connection.get_operation_result.to_s